# Accidentally deleted bootcamp drivers, stuck on windows 10 how can I restore macOS

Tags: bootcamp, windows, restore

I accidentally deleted all of my bootcamp drivers on my mid-2015 iMac by undergoing a windows reset which I did not realize deleted all of my bootcamp drivers. I am currently stuck on windows with no backups to restore to. My Mac partition is not being read by Windows but Windows has not taken up the space the old partion would have.

How would I go about restoring access to my macOS side?

Comment: try holding option key

Comment: What happens when you hold down the Option key immediately after turning on or restarting your Mac? Do you get the Startup Manager? Have a look at. [Mac startup key combinations](https://support.apple.comHT201255). and also [How to select a different startup disk](https://support.apple.com/HT202796).

Comment: I tried holding option down but it completely ignored it and booted into windows.